# How do I restore from a Windows backup on Fedora?

Tags: linux, backup, fedora, restore

I backed up my computer (Vista) before I switched to Fedora. I find that I badly need to restore to the backup I made, but am having trouble figuring out how. what I need to know is if I CAN restore to a Windows backup, and if so, how?

Comment: How did you backup your windows installation (what tools, what media)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you used the built-in Windows Backup package that creates .BKF backup files, your best bet is probably the [mtftar utility from Internet Connection](http://gpl.internetconnection.net/) (usage examples on [SavvyAdmin](http://savvyadmin.com/extract-nt-backup-files-in-linux-using-mtftar/) and an [old Digg thread](http://digg.com/news/story/Backup_tips:_reading_Windows_NTBackup_files_%28.bkf%29_from_Linux)).